# How to integrate Jenkins and Nexus (without maven)

Tags: jenkins, integration, nexus

jenkins and nexus are installed in docker containers on the same machine. All guides describe how to do the integration using the maven. But what if I just need to upload files from Jenkins to Nexus? I know that this can be done through a plugin "Nexus Artifact Uploader", but I don’t understand exactly how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Nexus Artifact Uploader`, you need to fill up the following details:

> Note: Below are the sample example data and the pre-requisite is to have a repository created in nexus.

- **Nexus Version:** NEXUS3 (Type of Nexus Repository Manager ex. NEXUS2 or NEXUS3)
- **Protocol:** HTTP (Protocol used for Nexus setup ex. HTTP or HTTPS)
- **Nexus URL:** localhost:8081 (URL of Nexus)
- **Credentials:** nexus-admin (credentials used to access nexus)
- **GroupId:** portal (unique base name of the company or group that created the project)
- **Version:** 1.0 (version of the project)
- **Repository:** maven-releases (name of the repository where you want to upload the artifacts)
- **ArtifactId:** web-portal (a unique name of the project)
- **Type:** tar.gz (type of artifact packaging like zip, tar, war, jar etc)
- **File:** web-portal.tar.gz (File path in the workspace. ex: artifact.zip or artifact.jar)

Find the screenshot as well:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The most simple way to connect you nexus with Jenkins - and Nexus OSS is using the maven setting.xml
Many tutorials are very complicated - the solution is more easy than it seems.

**Step 1**: create in your nexus an user with with deploy roles

**Step 2**: create in your Jenkins (Config File Provider Plugin) a setting.xml with the following entry:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>local-nexus</id>
        <username>mvn-deployer</username>
        <password>mvn-deployer</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

**Step 3**: enter in your project pom.xml the deployment information:

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>local-nexus</id>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8082/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>local-nexus</id>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8082/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-nexus</id>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8082/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Step 4**: create a maven jenkins build project

**Step 5**: as least you just need to run the mvn command deploy.

Don't forget to expose for your docker containers all necessary ports

Comment: "(without maven)"